# Accessing data within a php array to create a new array of results

Tags: php, arrays, web, service

I'm calling a web service using SOAP in PHP which is returning the data which I am then converting to an array using:

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($response), True);
```

This gives me the following when calling print_r($array):

```
{"Transactions":[{"MerchantAccount":"Test Account","Owner":"Test Owner","CustomerName":"Lisa Jobs"},
{"MerchantAccount":"Test Account","Owner":"Test Owner","CustomerName":"Lisa Jobs2"},
{"MerchantAccount":"Test Account","Owner":"Test Owner","CustomerName":"Lisa Jobs3"},
{"MerchantAccount":"Test Account","Owner":"Test Owner","CustomerName":"Lisa Jobs4"}]}
```

Could someone point me in the right direction so that I have an array full of Transactions please? (as in get rid of the first part of the string "Transactions"

I've tried print_r($array['Transactions']); but that is giving me an error:

```
Warning:  Illegal string offset
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the bare data from the WSDL:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [TransactionsSinceTicksResult] => 

        {"Transactions":[
{"MerchantAccount":"Test","Owner":"Test Owner","CustomerName":"Lisa Bloggs"},
{"MerchantAccount":"Test","Owner":"Test Owner","CustomerName":"Lisa Bloggs2"},
{"MerchantAccount":"Test","Owner":"Test Owner","CustomerName":"Lisa Bloggs3"}

        ]}
    )
)
```

**UPDATE**:

Function:

```
function getTransactions($sinceTicks) {

    global $userEmailAddress;
    global $userPassword;
    global $accountGatewayUser;
    global $accountGatewayPassword;

    $format = 'JSON';

    $wsdl = 'https://apps.blahblahblah.co.uk/recurring-payments/Services/Merchant.asmx?WSDL';

    try {
        $soapclient = new SoapClient($wsdl);

        $params = array ( 
            'userEmailAddress' => $userEmailAddress,
            'userPassword' => $userPassword,
            'accountGatewayUser' => $accountGatewayUser,
            'accountGatewayPassword' => $accountGatewayPassword,
            'format' => $format,
            'sinceTicks' => $sinceTicks
        );

        $response = $soapclient->TransactionsSinceTicks($params);

        $array = json_decode($response[0]->TransactionsSinceTicksResult, True);

        return ($array['Transactions']); 


        }
    catch(SoapFault $error) {
        return json_encode($error);
    }

}
```

This is returning: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue would seem to be here why is the response being encoded?

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($response), True);
```

My assumption is that your `$response` is json already so you're json encoding a json string when that is decoded you get the json string back... just try

```
$array = json_decode($response, TRUE);

//$array should be an array now

print_r($array['Transactions']); //should work
```

**UPDATES BASED ON NEW WSDL**

Based on the additional data you need to get to the transactions you can do something like:

```
$array = json_decode($response[0]->TransactionsSinceTicksResult, TRUE);
```

The data seems to be an array with 1 value hence '$response[0]'. Based on the output that is an object so you need to use the accessor `->`.

**My Test Logic**

Below is my test logic creating and object that matches what you provide. I am not sure where your issue is but what I have here matches the data provided and does what is asked for.

```
<?php
$trs = [
  "Transactions"=> [
    [
      "MerchantAccount"=> "Test",
      "Owner"=> "Test Owner",
      "CustomerName"=> "Lisa Bloggs"
    ],
    [
      "MerchantAccount"=> "Test",
      "Owner"=> "Test Owner",
      "CustomerName"=> "Lisa Bloggs2"
    ],
    [
      "MerchantAccount"=> "Test",
      "Owner"=> "Test Owner",
      "CustomerName"=> "Lisa Bloggs3"
    ]
  ]
];

$response = [new stdClass];

$response[0]->TransactionsSinceTicksResult = json_encode($trs);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($response); //Shows the structure you provided.

//No Errors works fine
$array = json_decode($response[0]->TransactionsSinceTicksResult, TRUE);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, If I don't decode / encode I get an error saying json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, but that maybe because the original data I'm getting is slightly different, so I've updated my original question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply again, unfortunately with that line I'm getting the error: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in...

I think we're on the right tracks though as you're correct, the data is in an array at [0] but I have no control of what it's sending me.

Comment: Thanks again for your help - I'm still getting the error I'm afraid. I've posted up the code just to double check that I'm doing things correctly.

Comment: @MichaelBellamy I put in what I used to test. I am not sure the issue but if your response structure is not the same then I am not going to be able to help much...

Comment: You've been a great help - your test code pointed me in the right direction so thank you very much.

I ended up having to do this:


        $response->TransactionsSinceTicksResult = json_encode($response);

        $array = json_decode($response->TransactionsSinceTicksResult, TRUE);
        $array = json_decode($array['TransactionsSinceTicksResult'], TRUE);

Comment: @MichaelBellamy I am glad you go something to work but what you have there I am going to be frank looks very odd... What is `$response` before you do anything to it ie `print_r($response)`

Comment: stdClass Object
(
    [TransactionsSinceTicksResult] => {"Transactions":[{"MerchantAccount":"HiddenData","Owner":"Data","CustomerName":"Lilly"},{"MerchantAccount":"HiddenData","Owner":"Data","CustomerName":"Lilly2"},{"MerchantAccount":"HiddenData","Owner":"Data","CustomerName":"Lilly3"}]}
)

Comment: @MichaelBellamy So where did that output come from in your question? Your `$response` comes back as an Object. So you can do this `$array = json_decode($response->TransactionsSinceTicksResult);`

Comment: To be honest I've been trying a million and one different conditions today so I can't actually remember what did that. Using your code above basically gives me the same information but has converted it from a stdClass to an Array. But it's not an array of Transactions, it still has the TransactionsSinceTicksResult at the beginning. Is that what you would expect?